# 2013 Foundation - Struggling to get versions to match

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, migration, versioning, patching

I am doing a migration and, prior to importing the databases on the new server, I am trying to match the versions.

I need to get to version 15.0.4833.1000.
Currently the new server is version 15.0.4420.1017.

having looked at [Todd Klindts Sharepoint admin blog](http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=346) and speaking with an MS Engineer, I was advised I need to download:

- 15.0.4571.1502*
  ​Service Pack 1 Mark 2 ​SharePoint Foundation 2013 ​KB2880551 ​Download ​Bugs, Notes, and Regressions
- ​​15.0.4605.1000 ​April 2014 CU ​​SharePoint Foundation 2013 KB2863892 ​Download ​​Bugs, Notes, and Regressions
- 15.0.4615.1001 ​MS14-022 ​SharePoint Foundation 2013 ​KB2952166 ​Links in KB ​Bugs, Notes, and Regressions
- 15.0.4833.1003 ​June 2016 CU ​SharePoint Foundation 2013 ​KB3115171 ​Download ​Bugs, Notes, and Regressions​​​​

I'm having a problem with 15.0.4605.1000, as this is a hotfix email request and when the mail comes over from MS with the download, the file eventually downloaded doesnt match KB2863892 and tells me 'there are no affected products on this system'.

Is anyone able to help me get these versions matching? I'm going crazy with this :(

Comment: I was also struggeling with old updates. I did a windows update and included also sharepoint updates. That fixed for me the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you dont need to install the hotfix And MS14-202 due to fact that latest CU include all the previous fix.I would do the following way.

- Install the Service Pack 1 Mark 2.( as this is base line for future updates.
- Now install the June CU 2016( requirement for it is Service Pack 1). You can get more info from this official blog :[June 2016 CU for SharePoint 2013 product family is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/06/14/june-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/)

Finally run the sharepoint config wizard from the Start Menu.

I am sure after this your farm will be same level. On a side note, if you want to install MS14, you can install it.

Comment: No matter what i install, the version won't go past 15.0.4420.1017.

Comment: I have installed service pack 1 mk 2 and also the CU 2016... am i doing something wrong? Any help appriciated, I'm desperate

Comment: did you run the config wizard after installing the CUp/SP? version will not change untill wizard complete

Comment: Without sounding too dumb, how does one do that?

Comment: On which windows server you are? Open the search bar and look for "sharepoint 2016 Products Configuration Wizard" and run it

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 running Sharepoint 2013 Foundation... I will look now

Comment: check this post, 2nd half running the sharepoint config wizard...http://www.jppinto.com/2013/10/how-to-install-the-march-2013-pu-and-august-2013-cu-on-sharepoint-2013/